# Source code is empty in shipment observer magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, multi-source-inventory

I am trying to get source_code from the shipment_id

Have used below event.

**Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<event name="sales_order_shipment_save_after">
    <observer name="sales_order_shipment_after"
              instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SalesOrderShipmentAfter" />
</event>
```

Then **Vendor\Module\Observer\SalesOrderShipmentAfter.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\InventoryShipping\Model\ResourceModel\ShipmentSource\GetSourceCodeByShipmentId;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceInterface;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceRepositoryInterface;
class SalesOrderShipmentAfter implements ObserverInterface
{ 
 protected $shipmentNotifier;
 protected $_logger;
 protected $_httpClientFactory; 
 protected $orderRepository;
 protected $_customerRepository;
 protected $sourceRepository;
 public function __construct(
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,       
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\ShipmentNotifier $shipmentNotifier,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\ZendClientFactory $httpClientFactory, 
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
    GetSourceCodeByShipmentId $sourceCodeByShipmentId,
    SourceRepositoryInterface $sourceRepository
) {
    $this->_logger = $logger;
    $this->shipmentNotifier = $shipmentNotifier;
    $this->_httpClientFactory   = $httpClientFactory; 
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->_customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->sourceCodeByShipmentId = $sourceCodeByShipmentId;
    $this->sourceRepository = $sourceRepository;
}

 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    try{
        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        $shipmentId = $shipment->getId();
        $this->_logger->info('--shipmentId--'.$shipmentId);                     
        if(isset($shipmentId) && $shipmentId != ''){
            $sourceCode = $this->getSource($shipmentId);
            $this->_logger->info('--sourceCode--'.$sourceCode);
            
            $sourceInfo = $this->sourceRepository->get($sourceCode);
            $this->_logger->info('--sourceInfo--'.json_encode($sourceInfo));
        }
     }catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->_logger->info('--shipment observer--'.$e->getMessage());
     } 
   return $this;    
 }
  public function getSource($shipmentId)
   {
    return $this->sourceCodeByShipmentId->execute($shipmentId);
   }
}
```

from the above code i am getting the shipment Id but not the source_code,

Can anyone help me how to get this.